# kube-prometheus-stack node-exporter basic auth

Tags: kube-prometheus-stack

I'm using the kube-prometheus-stack helm chart.  The piece I'm trying to alter is my node exporters, specifically the actual exporters on the actual nodes that make up the cluster (kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter).  These exporters run on the external IPs so the data by default is available to all on hostname:9100/metrics.
Any ideas on how to get node exporter basic auth running via the chart install?

I know the node-exporter supports this as I have nodes outside of my cluster that run this way.

I've been able to register external resources with the CDR scrapconfig using auth, that works great.
Just tryign to find a way to lock that data down a bit.